# Jump is not smooth, more like teleportation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Player is, like the title said, more teleporting like jumping but I don't find an answer for it. I used this is my Code

```
void Jumping()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && currentJumps <= maxJumps)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        currentJumps++;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the `Jumping()` function called?

Comment: U mean where ? i tried in Update and FIxedUpdate...when this is what you mean

Comment: Yes, could you give us some context as to where and how `Jumping()` is called? As in show us some more code.

Comment: Sorry but i cant follow you :D hmmm, so its in the fixedupdate and everytime i pressed space if i am on the ground

Comment: Yes that's what I'm referring to. So if in `FixedUpdate()` you are checking if space is pressed, why are you checking again in `Jumping()`? This might have nothing to do with your issue but it's confusing based on what information has been provided.

Comment: ohhh okay sorry my mistake ... no i check in Jumping() if space is pressed and the function is in the FixedUpdate

Comment: no when you are on the ground you can jump three times and than go back to the ground :)

Comment: Have you tried modifying the rigidbody mass and jumpForce values to see if it has an effect?

Comment: if i set the jumpforce higher the player teleports higher and if i set the mass higher he doenst make anything

Comment: My final suggestion would be to move `Jumping()` to the `Update()` instead of `FixedUpdate()` and then try messing with the mass / jumpForce values again.

Answer (score 0):

Input.GetKeyDown needs to be called from your `Update()` function, and Physics Forces should be applied in your `FixedUpdate()` function.

> GetKeyDown is only true for the one frame in which it occurs.
>   FixedUpdate may or may not run during that frame. So, never use
>   GetKeyDown (or any of the other similar Down and Up input options) in
>   FixedUpdate.
>   https://forum.unity.com/threads/fixedupdate-and-input-getkeydown.56862/

E.g. This could make your code look something like this:

```
private bool _jumping;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        _jumping = true;
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        _jumping = false;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
     if (_jumping) rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Also note:

**Input.GetKeyDown**

> Returns true during the frame the user starts pressing down the key
>   identified by name.
>   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

**Input.GetKey**

> Returns true while the user holds down the key identified by name.
>   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

**Input.GetKeyUp**

> Returns true during the frame the user releases the key identified by
>   name. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html

---

**How I usually implement jumping:**

I tend to use GetKeyDown to detect the start of a jump, check if `_jumping` is false, set it to true.

I have a float value which is my force multiplier (your `jumpForce`) for the jump, which starts off high and decreases throughout the duration of the jump.

I decrease this in `FixedUpdate` through `jumpForce = Mathf.Max(jumpForce - jumpDecay * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0)`.

If `Input.GetKeyUp` is detected and `_jumping == true`, set `jumpForce = 0`. *(Stop jumping)*

On collision with ground, set `_jumping` to false and set `jumpForce = maxJumpForce`.

In `FixedUpdate`, check if `_jumping` then apply a force using our `jumpForce`.

This results in a behaviour where the longer you hold jump, the longer your jump, similar to games like Mario and Hollow Knight